# how to call call Graphql APIs with HTTP requester in Mulesoft

Tags: graphql, dataweave, mulesoft

I need to consume a graphQL API in Mule 4.
i draft below json code in dataweave, then use HTTP requestor to post the payload.
but still return Invalid Syntax, may i know is it possible to post data to graphQL API
in Mule 4? what's syntax error in below code?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
query: "query{
    test (first: 10, status: \"ACTIVE\" ) {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                ref
                type
                status
                attributes {
                    name
                    value
                    type
                }
            }
        }
    }"
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error, is it after getting the response from the GraphQL API, or is Mule throwing an error before sending the request? Have you tried sending the same request using Postman of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to post data to GraphQL API in Mule 4. The Error that you are getting is probably because you are missing a closing parenthesis in your query. Try this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    query: "query{
        test (first: 10, status: \"ACTIVE\" ) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    ref
                    type
                    status
                    attributes {
                        name
                        value
                        type
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }"
}
```